# ¿Como ocultar la url en laravel cuando usas get para editar?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Deseo editar un registro mediante su id y tengo el siguiente código en mi vista:

```
<a href="{{route('guest.edit',$g->id)}}" class="btn btn-simple btn-warning btn-icon edit"><i class="ti-pencil-alt"></i></a>
```

Y asi tengo en mi ruta:

```
Route::resource('guest','GuestController');
```

Luego en mi controlador:

```
public function edit($id){
    $guest=Guest::find($id);
    return view('Guests.edit1',compact('guest'));
}
```

El problema con esto es que en mi ruta me aparece el id, lo cual considero no es seguro, aparece de esta forma

```
http://localhost:8081/guest/2/edit
```

Como soluciono de tal forma que no se muestre el id en el url, o no se muestre del todo el url

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Una posible solución sería emplear [Encryption](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/encryption) para  mostrar su parámetro encriptado. Desde la vista , emplearía  `encrypt` desde `blade`

```
<a href="{{route('guest.edit',Crypt::encrypt($g->id))}}"
```

Para luego en el controlador desencriptar este valor.

```
public function edit($id){
  $id =  Crypt::decrypt($id);
  $guest=Guest::find($id);
  return view('Guests.edit1',compact('guest'));
}
```

No olvidar  `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;`

Comment: Gracias  Dev. Joel me la muestra así ahora eyJpdiI6IklybzdFXC9jdGFod2ltWEVMNll1SlBnPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6Ijk1QXJlZ29INE54QWlwQXEzUXZuc0E9PSIsIm1hYyI6Ijc0YjUxNzkwNDA3NDJmNzhkMzA1MzU0NjU2NWI3Mjg2OTFiYTA1OGZkOTkyZGYxYjJlMzcxNTUxMjQ5ODI3ZGUifQ. Si existe algún otro método, no duden en compartirlo

Comment: Sí desea algo más "seguro" , creo que es la mejor opción, Saludos.

Comment: Intenta usar una libreria llamada hashids que te lo encripta no tanto pero keda mas legible

Comment: esta es la mejor solución que e encontrado muchas gracias!, no me gusta bajar paquetes y paquetes de librerías extra ya que se acumulan y se siente un exceso para algo tan simple (tal ves si toda la herramientas es prioritario el control de id/url s

Comment: esta solución la encuentro muy segura, pero obliga a configurar esto por cada ruta y funcion en controller que tenga el proyecto. Existe alguna manera de hacer una sola configuración y no tener que ir función por función configurando esto??

Answer (score 3):

Encontré la mejor solución al problema utilizando `FakeID`.

Enmascara todos los ids de tu modelo, simplemente colocando el *namespace* y el *trait*, va a ocultar tu id y te generará un URL muy limpio, ejemplo, si tienes algo como esto:

```
localhost/2/editar
```

Lo cambiara por algo como esto:

```
Localhost/97302855/editar
```

No tienes que preocuparte por *encriptar o desencriptar*, lo realiza todo automáticamente.

> https://github.com/Propaganistas/Laravel-FakeId

Answer (score 2):

También podrías intentarlo con el uso de urls amigables, tienes una url mas limpia y logras ocultar el id.

Yo uso este paquete https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable te permite generar url amigables de una forma sencilla.

Answer (score 1):

Intentalo asi con un alias sobre la ruta:

```
Route::get('/url/{id}',[
   'uses'=>'Controller@metodo',
    'as'=>'registration'
]);
```

o tambien con este helper de laravel:

```
Hash::make($id)
```

Comment: Hice de esta manera con el alias, no se si lo habré aplicado bien, pero aun me sigue mostrando la ruta en mi route hice esto: Route::get('editarg/{id}',[
   'uses'=>'GuestController@edit',
    'as'=>'edicion'
]); en la vista asi: <a href="{{route('edicion',$g->id)}}" class="btn btn-simple btn-warning btn-icon edit"><i class="ti-pencil-alt"></i></a> y me muestra aun la url: http://localhost:8081/editarg/3

Answer (score 1):

sé que ya es un poco tarde pero acabo de hallar una posible solución.

1. Creas un nuevo policy ligado a tu modelo `php artisan make:policy NombrePolicy -m nombreModelo`. Vas a app->HTTP->policies.
2. Encotraras diferentes funciones como "create,view view any, etc." eliges la de interés en mi caso yo escogí wiew ya que no encontré el  edit.
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora aquí hay dos maneras que yo observo...

1. obtienes las url de la página que visitas ejemplo http://.../usuario/560/edit con  `$urlUserBase=request()->url();`. Después obtengo la ruta de edit pero del usuario actual con  `$urlUserActual=route('usuario.edit',['usuario'=>$user->id]);`
   retornas comparando que si son idénticos `return $urlUserActual === $urlUserBase;`
   en tu controller escribes `//Verifica el policy User@update $this->authorize('función',$varConArrayUsuario);`
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado es éste:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y la otra la puesdes checar [aqui](https://www.udemy.com/course/curso-laravel-crea-aplicaciones-y-sitios-web-con-php-y-mvc/learn/lecture/20325235#overview)

Comment: El código debe ir como texto por favor

Comment: ¡Sí!, muchas gracias